# Как задать параметр по умолчанию с типом ассоциативной коллекции?

Tags: oracle, plsql, коллекции

Создаю тип данных `RECORD` и с ним создаю ассоциативную коллекцию. Хочу передавать эту коллекцию в процедуру как параметр по умолчанию.

Пробую с `NULL`, вот упрощённый пример:

```
declare
    type rec is record (a int, b int);
    type tab is table of rec index by pls_integer;
    
    procedure proc (t tab default null) is
    begin 
        null; /*
        Логика процедуры */
    end;
begin 
    proc; 
end;
/
```

Но компилятор даёт ошибку:

> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 5, column 35:
> PLS-00382: expression is of the wrong type

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can we use a table type parameter as a default null parameter in PLSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44697981) от участника [@Dinidu Hewage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615830/dinidu-hewage)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/44697981

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR Ассоциативная коллекция не может быть `NULL`. При обьявлении она пустая, но не `NULL`. Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-8060F01F-B53B-48D4-9239-7EA8461C2170):

> 5.2 Associative Arrays
> Like a database table, an associative array:
>
> Is empty (**but not null**) until you populate it

Для параметра по умолчанию можно задать пустую коллекцию. Для ассоциативной коллекции не сушествует функции конструктора, но можно указать любую функцию, которая возвращает пустую коллекцию:

```
declare
    type rec is record (a int, b int);
    type tab is table of rec index by pls_integer;
    
    procedure proc (t tab default cast (null as tab)) is
    begin null; 
        if t.count > 0 then null;
        /* Логика процедуры */ end if;
    end;
    
    function emptytab return tab is
        ret tab; 
    begin return ret; end;
    procedure proc2 (t tab default emptytab) is
    begin null; 
        if t.count > 0 then null;
        /* Логика процедуры */ end if;
    end;
begin null; 
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Начиная с 19c в качестве конструктора можно использовать [*Qualified Expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758):

```
declare
    type tab is table of int index by pls_integer;
    procedure proc (t tab default tab ()) is
    begin null; 
        if t.count > 0 then null;
        /* Логика процедуры */ end if;
    end;
begin null; 
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```